# What is the default random: argument in Ruby's Array#shuffle

Tags: ruby, random

The documentation for [`Array#shuffle`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/Array.html#method-i-shuffle) states:

> `shuffle(random: rng) → new_ary`
>
> The optional `rng` argument will be used as the random number generator.
>
> ```
> a.shuffle(random: Random.new(1))  #=> [1, 3, 2]
> ```

If I *don't* supply the optional `random` argument, what is used for it?

Equivalently, if I call `a.shuffle(random: rng)`, what does `rng` need to be to make it the same as just `a.shuffle`?

Comment: Click the "Click to Toggle Source" button.

Comment: The syntax `random: Random` on the page you link is not an indication of a type signature (as `:` is used for in many other languages). It's actually a declaration that the default value for that parameter *is* the value `Random`, which is a class object in the standard library.

Comment: D'oh, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's right in the signature, `shuffle(random: Random)`. That says the default value for `random` is the [`Random` Class object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/Random.html).

> The class method `Random.rand` provides the base functionality of `Kernel.rand` along with better handling of floating point values. These are both interfaces to the Ruby system PRNG.